# Facebook User id's of Fans on my facebook Page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i a looking to access the ids of fans of my page on facebook to show their profile info on my site.
How can i do it?? Do i have to create an Facebook Application for that???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now they don't provide the user ids like in old rest api http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page.